# Going back from child window to parent window in Visual C++

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

I am using the winForm in Visual c++ to build my program. From the first window i need to move to another window on a button click. For this i am using the below code and it works fine.

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(Object^  sender, EventArgs^  e) {
     this->Hide();
     Form2^ pp = gcnew Form2();
     pp->ShowDialog();
}
```

However i need a Back button on the child window which on click would hide/disable it and show the parent window. How can i achieve this?

Comment: You may declare you main form as `static` so that pp can reach the main form.

Comment: i tried that but no result

Comment: The `ShowDialog` method creates a modal dialog that disables its parent. So if you pass the parent window handle to the `ShowDialog` method, there's no reason you have to hide the parent. When the dialog is dismissed, the parent is automatically re-enabled and still visible.

Comment: yes but i need a back button...a button click event should take back to the parent

Comment: You cannot hide or disable a dialog.  That would make the app unusable since the dialog is the only enabled window.  So you might as well have your back button close the dialog, problem solved.  Or just don't use ShowDialog.

Comment: @hans disabling the dialog would leave the parent disabled but I think hiding it should be fine. The actual Windows Window handles could be destroyed leaving the .net objects available for inspection. Not sure if it actually works that way however.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you want to do some navigation kind of things then, Your code of going parent to child is also not work properly.

Now what I suggest you is that for going from parent to child create one global variable.
Like ,

```
Form2^ pp ;
```

initialise it in constructor or create method of parent class

Like,

```
 //Create method or constructor,
 pp = gcnew Form2();
```

And do your navigation
Like,

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
      this->Hide();
      pp->ShowDialog();    
}
```

In this case no matter how many time you click on button3 only one instance of child class will show and hide.

No your problem is that you want go back to parent window form from child window. You may achieve this using **this.Parent as Form**

Like,

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    this->Hide();
    Form parentForm = (this.Parent as Form);
    parentForm ->Show();
}
```